# jQuery Ajax Having Problems Loading PHP File as designed

Tags: ajax, jquery

The following jQuery's goal is to load images from a server, and then control the number of images per page, as well as navigate through the pages. It's not functioning. 
I'm hoping someone can shed some light on whats wrong with it.

I've gotten the pagination to work, but then the combo box page selector doesn't work. I've gotten the combo box selector to work, but then the images and pagination won't load. Right now only the combo box is showing, and although it looks as if *it* works, no images are visible, so it's hard to tell.

**The HTML:**

```
<div id="loading"></div>
<div id="gallery_container">
    <ul class="new_arrivals_gallery"></ul>
    <div class="pagination"></div>
</div>
<form>
    <label>Images Number:</label>
    <select id="imgNum" name="imgNum">
        <option value="12">12</option>
        <option value="16">16</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>      
    </select>
</form>
```

**The jQuery:**

```
slideshow = { page: 0, imgs: '' };

function loadData(){
    loading_show();
    gallery_hide();                    
    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "GET",
        url: "new_arrivals_data.php",
        data: slideshow,
        success: function(msg) {
            gallery_show();
            $("#gallery_container").html(msg);
            console.log(msg);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // Tell the human that something broke.
        },
        complete: function() {
            // This is always called regardless of success or failure.
            loading_hide();
        }
    });
}
loadData(1);  // For first time page load default results
$('#gallery_container .pagination li.active').live('click',function(){
    slideshow.page = $('#gallery_container .pagination li.active').attr('p');
    loadData();
});           
$('#go_btn').live('click',function(){
    slideshow.page = parseInt($('.goto').val());
    var no_of_pages = parseInt($('.total').attr('a'));
    if(page != 0 && page <= no_of_pages){
        loadData();
    }else{
        alert('Enter a PAGE between 1 and '+no_of_pages);
        $('.goto').val("").focus();
        return false;
    }
});

//Bind the onChange event to Fetch images on combox selection
$("#imgNum").change(function(){
    console.log('hi');
    slideshow.imgs = $('imgNum').val();
    loadData();
})
//You should store the current selected option in a cookie
//For the sake of the example i'll set the default permanently to 12
var imgNum_selected = 12;

//set the initial selected option and trigger the event
$("#imgNum [value='"+imgNum_selected+"']")
    .prop("selected","selected");
    $("#imgNum").change();
```

***The Original Code***

**The HTML:**

```
<div id="loading"></div>
<div id="gallery_container">
    <ul class="new_arrivals_gallery"></ul>
    <div class="pagination"></div>    
</div>
<form>
    <label>Images Number:</label>
    <select id="imgNum" name="imgNum">
        <option value="12">12</option>
        <option value="16">16</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>      
    </select>
</form>
```

**The jQuery Ajax:**

```
function loading_show(){
    $('#loading').html("<img src='loading.gif'/>").fadeIn('fast');
}
function loading_hide(){
    $('#loading').fadeOut('fast');
}                
function gallery_show(){
    $('#gallery_container').fadeIn('slow');
}
function gallery_hide(){
    $('#gallery_container').fadeOut(10);
}

function loadData(page){
    loading_show();
    gallery_hide();                    
    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "GET",
        url: "new_arrivals_data.php",
        data: {page:page, imgs: value},
        success: function(msg)
        {
            $("#gallery_container").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings)
            {
                gallery_show();
                loading_hide();
                $("#gallery_container").html(msg);
            });
        }
    });
}
loadData(1);  // For first time page load default results
$('#gallery_container .pagination li.active').live('click',function(){
    var page = $(this).attr('p');
    loadData(page);
});           
$('#go_btn').live('click',function(){
    var page = parseInt($('.goto').val());
    var no_of_pages = parseInt($('.total').attr('a'));
    if(page != 0 && page <= no_of_pages){
        loadData(page);
    }else{
        alert('Enter a PAGE between 1 and '+no_of_pages);
        $('.goto').val("").focus();
        return false;
    }
});

//Bind the onChange event to Fetch images on combox selection
$("#imgNum").change(function(){
    //The combo box
    var sel = $(this);
    //Selected value
    var value = sel.val();
    loadData(page);
})
//You should store the current selected option in a cookie
//For the sake of the example i'll set the default permanently to 12
var imgNum_selected = 12;

//set the initial selected option and trigger the event
$("#imgNum [value='"+imgNum_selected+"']")
    .prop("selected","selected")
    .change();
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get this working. Specifically the jQuery as the HTML was fine.

I am thinking there are still some general clean ups I could do to this. If you have any advice, please let me know!

**Here is the functioning code:**

```
(function() {
    var page;

    function loading_show(){
        $('#loading').html("<img src='loading.gif'/>").fadeIn('fast');
    }
    function loading_hide(){
        $('#loading').fadeOut('fast');
    }                
    function gallery_show(){
        $('#gallery_container').fadeIn('slow');
    }
    function gallery_hide(){
        $('#gallery_container').fadeOut(10);
    }


    function loadData(page, imgs){
        loading_show();
        gallery_hide();                    
        $.ajax
        ({
            type: "GET",
            url: "new_arrivals_data.php",
            data: {page:page, imgs:imgs},
            success: function(msg) {
                $("#gallery_container").html(msg);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                // Tell the human that something broke.
            },
            complete: function() {
                // This is always called regardless of success or failure.
                gallery_show();
                loading_hide();
            }
        });
    }
    loadData(1);  // For first time page load default results
    $('#gallery_container .pagination li.active').live('click',function(){
        var imgs = $("#imgNum").val();
        var page = $(this).attr('p');
        loadData(page, imgs);
    });           
    $('#go_btn').live('click',function(){
        var imgs = $("#imgNum").val();
        var page = parseInt($('.goto').val());
        var no_of_pages = parseInt($('.total').attr('a'));
        if(page != 0 && page <= no_of_pages){
            loadData(page, imgs);
        }else{
            alert('Enter a PAGE between 1 and '+no_of_pages);
            $('.goto').val("").focus();
            return false;
        }
    });

    //Bind the onChange event to Fetch images on combox selection
    $("#imgNum").change(function(){
        //The combo box
        var sel = $(this);
        //Selected images value
        var imgs = sel.val();
        var page = $('#cur_page').attr('cur_page');
        //Feth the images
        loadData(page, imgs);
    })
    //You should store the current selected option in a cookie
    //For the sake of the example i'll set the default permanently to 12
    var imgNum_selected = 16;

    //set the initial selected option and trigger the event
    $("#imgNum [value='"+imgNum_selected+"']").prop("selected","selected").change();

}());
```

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

This might fix it:

Wrap the loadData(1); line in jQuery's document ready function like this:

```
$(document).ready(){
  loadData(1)
}
```

EDIT:

OR

1.
    var value = sel.val()

Value is a keyword, don't use it as a variable name.

2.

```
$("#imgNum...")
```

Needs to be in the $(document).ready(function(){here});

3.

```
loadData(1);
```

Doesn't need the 1.

4.
It doesn't look like li.active is being returned in the AJAX, but it's being referenced in the jQuery

5.
The HTML of #gallery_container should be loaded before gallery_show() is called

Comment: it could be that this line: _loadData(1)_ needs a semicolon at the end... maybe?

Comment: I tried all of the above. Still getting a syntax error. Would it not be just as good to wrap the entire code with a $(document).ready()?

Comment: Really you _should_ only need to have the first function in the ready event. Unless other events are being called. Can you post a link to the page?

Comment: I managed to get the syntax error to go away, but to no avail. It still isn't functioning. I've attempted a lot with this code on my own. Do you think it might be beneficial if I show you the original?

Comment: this is all being done on my local host. Any chance I could send you the files? I'll post the original code in a minute. I'll also see if I can make it live, but you still wouldn't be able to see the PHP no?

Comment: Ok, The original code is posted. I hope it sheds more light on what's wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your help. I managed to get it working. It was all in the jQuery and I will post the correct code. Let me know what you think.